# Extjs MVC manipulating associated data

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I have a User model which hasMany Orders and many Articles.
If I want to delete a User record I go by record.remove() if I'm not mistaken but how do I delete all orders of this user for example?

Logically I would go by record.getAssociatedData('orders').remove() but 'getAssociatedData' does not accept any parameters.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This may be ok for fetching data but not for deleting! This action belongs to the DataBase or at least the server. It is really bad to do the referential integrity on the client! Don't to this.

Comment: And how would you write a html5 app with websqlstorage if not this way? Stop telling people what "not" to do unless you're sure about what you write. You may confuse other readers from knowing right from wrong.